# Using CNN for Bidding in Belote card game

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I have this idea to use CNN to learn a Belote Bidder.
We have 32 cards from which the bidder guy has only 5. I put them in an "image" 4x8, arr[r][s] = 1 if he has the card from suit s and rank r, and 0 if he doesnt.

Only 5 ones in the image.
Then I simulate N times the possible bids with Monte Carlo algorithm and make a vector with the probabilities for each bid. They sum to 1.

After this I try to learn the CNN but no matter what I do, it doesnt learn well and it doesnt generalize. Maybe the input data is not useful for CNN, perhaps I need to use something else, but the most important thing is - I need it to generalize well, because the computation of the output is very expensive, and I want to do it only once, save the CNN and then use it.

Comment: I forgot to mention, in the output data there is some noise, because Monte Carlo fails from time to time.. Let's say 1/10 outputs is not the correct output.